# JMockit throws "No class with name java_lang_System$currentTimeMillis" when used from Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, jmockit

A test that works in a .java file throws an exception when put into a .groovy file. Why is that?

- Groovy: 2.3.9
- JMockit: 1.20
- Java: 1.8.0_60

The code:

```
@Test
public void testSystemCurrentTimeMillis(@Mocked final System unused) {
    new NonStrictExpectations() {{
        System.currentTimeMillis(); result = 1438357206679L;
    }};
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Assert.assertEquals(1438357206679L, currentTime);
}
```

The exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No class with name "java_lang_System$currentTimeMillis" found

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at x.GroovyTest$1.<init>(GroovyTest.groovy:12)
    at x.GroovyTest.testSystemCurrentTimeMillis(GroovyTest.groovy:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: My initial thought is that the groovy parser gets confused with the `{{ ... }}` block in regards to a closure or block.

Comment: @tylerwal (I'm a Groovy noob:) Is there anything I can do to confirm / prevent that?

Comment: You can force the treatment of a block by a label: `MyLabel:{ ... }`; try enclosing the innermost block with a label.

Comment: @tylerwal I tried enclosing `System.currentTimeMillis(); result = 1438357206679L;`, and then `long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); Assert...` inside label blocks, to no avail.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with this syntax (`{{ ... }}`), but I found a good link explaining it: [DoubleBraceInitialization](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization) - I'm assuming there is a groovy way that does the same thing.